# Create a Javascript-like ScrollTo effect using only CSS3?

Tags: css, scroll

Is it possible to create a Javascript-like scrollTo effect using only CSS3? For instance:

```
<a href="#location">Button</a>
```

And somehow telling the window to smoothly scroll to that location? Using Javascript it is very easy, but CSS would be even more wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t think of any way to do it.

1. CSS’s animation facilities only allow you to change CSS properties, and there aren’t any that let you refer to the position of elements on-screen, or how much the page is scrolled.
2. The only way CSS can respond to elements being clicked on is via the `:active` and `:visited` selectors, and using `:visited` to animate a link doesn‘t seem to work.
3. You can use `:active` to animate the bottom margin of a link, but the animation will only run whilst the user is holding down the mouse button. See http://jsfiddle.net/w5kcr/1/